# Taylor series (mclauren), after 9 or 11, compiler writes;

Tags: c, math, formula, taylor-series

My formula for sin(x) in taylor series(picture under the code). In general if i enter Start 1 and end 20 with
step 2, console output '-nan' after x = 9; sin(X) and Taylor should be the same;,
for example:

x = 9;  sin(x) = 0.412118; taylor = 0.412118

x = 11; sin(x) = -0.99999; taylor -0.999976;

x = 13; sin(x) = 0.420167; taylor = -nan;

like this all the time;
i need some help; its for my laboratory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float a, b, left, right, eps = 0.00001, step, x, add = 1, chis, znam, fact, sum = 0, delta;
    printf("Plese enter your start: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Your end: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("and step: ");
    scanf("%f", &step);

    if (b < a || a < eps) {
        printf("Your inputs aren't correct");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\tX\t           sin(x)\tTaylor\t   Delta\n");
    for (x = a; x < b; x += step) {

        printf("    x = %9f\t", x);
        left = sin(x);
        printf("%9f", left);

        chis = -x;
        znam = 1;

        sum = 0;
        add = 1;
        fact = 1;
        while (fabs(add) > eps) {
            add = -1 * chis / znam;
            sum += add;
            chis *= -1 * (x * x);
            fact++;
            znam *= fact * (fact + 1);
            fact++;

        }
        printf("    %9f    ", sum);
        printf("%e\n", fabs(left - sum));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `znam` is +infinity when that happens

Comment: `fact` is 35 when that happens. That means you attempted to store 35! in `znam`. It must have overflowed.

Comment: Do you know how i can fix that?

Comment: Confirmed. 35! is 5166573983193072464833325668761600000000, which is more than 2^131. Than max for a single-precision IEEE float is around 2^127

Comment: Keep one number. Multiply it by `-1*x*x` and divide by `fact * (fact+1)` at each step.

Comment: For large values of `x`, you should reduce the value by a multiple of 2, so that `x` is always between 0 and 2. That will help keep the numerator from exploding.

Comment: do not calculate the factoral. Divide the number by all numbers from 2 to n. You will never overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`znam` is +inf because `fact` is 35, 35! is over 2^131, and the maximum positive single-precision floating pointer number is hair less than 2^128.

You could buy yourself some time by switching to double-precision floating point numbers. But that's not the right solution.

Currently, you are calculating the 17th term as

```
-1 * x^35 / 35!
```

But you could also calculate it as follows<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
previous_term * -1 * x / 34 * x / 35
```

This avoids very large intermediary numbers.

---

1. Math:

   ```
     -1 * x^35 / 35!
   = ( +1 * -1 ) * ( x^33 * x * x ) / ( 35 * 34 * 33! )
   = +1 * -1 * x^33 * x * x / 35 / 34 / 33!
   = ( +1 * x^33 / 33! ) * -1 * x * x / 35 / 34
   = previous_term * -1 * x / 34 * x / 35
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to calculate power or factorial:

```
double tailor(double x, unsigned n)
{
    double result = x;
    double part = x;
    int sign = -1;

    for(unsigned i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned dv = 2 * (i - 1) + 1 + 1; dv <= 2 * i + 1; dv++)
        {
            part *= x / (double)dv;
        }        
        result += sign * part;
        sign *= -1;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    for(unsigned n = 10; n < 60; n++)
        printf("n = %u : %.60f\n", n, tailor(13, n));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b1z3rszh8

You can add epsilon check quite easily instead of padding `n` from the caller